# LibreOffice UNO XStorage type name for Excel 2007/2010

Tags: c#, libreoffice, uno

I am trying to write a little utility that will convert from one spreadsheet type to another using LibreOffice (or OpenOffice, whatever), and I started by following the example [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Saving_Spreadsheet_Documents#Storing). It works fine and I can do some conversions, but I can't find the type name for Excel 2007/2010. The 97 type name is given in the document, but the location they suggest to look for the supported filters (from the documentation \share\config\registry\instance\org\openoffice\Office\TypeDetection.xml) doesn't exist on my system. So, anybody know off hand what the filter name is? Thanks.

P.S. I also tried looking at the source code for unoconv, but it didn't have a mapping either, although that code has not been updated for a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/9582/is-there-a-xlsx-filter-option/
The answer is "Calc MS Excel 2007 XML"